# No response to POST when serverside script uses SQLite3 commands

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, sqlite

I'm using AJAX to post the contents of a form to a web server. The client-side script should display an alert when a response is received. When the PHP script on the server-side only contains an echo the alert is displayed. When the PHP script contains SQLite3 commands the alert isn't displayed.

The web server is Apache2.

The HTML and client-side script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Register</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="login_style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <script>
    function register() {
        var emailAddress = document.getElementById("mail").value;
        $.post(
            "register.php",
            {email: emailAddress},
            function(response) {
                alert(response);
            });
    }
    </script>

    <h1>Register</h1>
    <label for="mail">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" id="mail">
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password">
    <button type="submit" onclick="register()">Register</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The server-side PHP:

```
<?php
$db = new SQLite3('user.db'); // The problem line.
printf("Response!\n");
?>
```

The output of "ls -l" /var/www/html/editor directory (contains the files):

```
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1922 Feb 14 12:36 login_style.css
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  878 Feb 14 12:36 register.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   65 Feb 14 12:36 register.php
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root    0 Feb 14 12:36 user.db
```

Interestingly, when I manually run the command "php5 register.php" on the command line while in the /var/www/html/editor directory then the script will echo "Response!" whether or not I comment out the SQLite3 line.

Any help would be much appreciated.